# calling function inside setInterval on onload event of image tag throwing error: undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the function calllogin when img tag is loaded after that the function should run continuously every 10000ms. It alerts calling but it doesn't call the function callogin

```
<script>
function calllogin(id){
console.log('calling calllogin function',id);
}

</script>
<img src="upload/thumb/image.jpg" alt="Ad Thumb" onload="alert('calling');setInterval(function(){calllogin(114)},10000);"/>
```

it throws the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calllogin is not defined(…)

Comment: try `onclick` .

Comment: its working fine for me. I get 114 in my console. I think problem is with img src.

Comment: @AmitJamwal yeah maybe image is not loaded so function won't be calling

Comment: Is the snippet exactly what you tried that raised the error? Is there anything you changed to maybe simplify or generalize the code? Assuming the image path is good, [the snippet doesn't result in the error you mentioned](http://jsbin.com/quwala/1/edit?html,console,output). Though, the error may be caused by a typo or by `calllogin`'s definition being wrapped in another `function`, including a `ready` or `load` event handler for the page. (If you're using a tool to test the code, check its options for any automatic event bindings.)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah typo mistake or tool problem that he is using .

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski thanks, it was a spelling error in function, I typed funtion instead of function.

Answer (score 0):

if image not loaded then `onload` function will not be called.

```js
function calllogin(id){
console.log('calling calllogin function',id);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Ad Thumb" onload="alert('calling');setInterval(function(){calllogin(114)},10000);"/>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, the problem was with the image, since it was not loaded correctly the onload even was not firing. I was also preparing a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/fo7dLhcf/4/) to answer. Missed in a minute :)

Comment: @SibeeshVenu but this is not his problem . since he was able to call the function it means the image has been loaded properly .